# How to redirect ettercap or arp poisoned traffic to burp suite or mitmproxy?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, burp-suite, arp-spoofing, ettercap

I have poisoned the target using Ettercap and redirected the traffic to my IP address. The question is, how to intercept and modify this traffic using burp suite or mitm proxy?

The only condition is, I cannot do any client-side modification. The target computer is also mine, but I have to prove to my manager, that I had done this without touching the Target computer. The traffic is HTTPS traffic.

Comment: And are we to assume that the traffic is HTTPS? Because there are numerous tutorials for how to modify unencrypted traffic with your setup.

Comment: @schroeder yes the traffic is HTTPS. Sorry forgot to mention this in the question. Is it possible to redirect the arp poisoned traffic to BurpSuite and intercept it there? I have been trying this for couple of days now. No luck :(

Comment: I think you are still missing details. You say that you redirected the traffic. Is that happening? What *exactly* is not happening that you want to happen? Do you know that Burp is not the tool you want to use for this? It's not designed for it

Comment: Reading the encrypted traffic will be extremely difficult with any tool. TLS is designed to prevent this.